# Can't get header Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I set the headers from an Express server written in NodeJS like that:

```
app.use('/routes', function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('test', 'test');
    next();
);
```

And they are sent to the client as it can be seen in the following image: 
[image: Headers]
Then I try to retrieve them in the Angular side like that:

```
return next.handle(newreq).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
});
```

But then, it's not displayed in the output of `console.log(event)`

[image: Headers output]
I also tried to use `event.headers.get('test')` with the same result

thanks.

Comment: Try instead doing `console.log(newReq.headers.get('test'))` and see if you get the desired output.

Comment: That doesn't work since I'm trying to get the header from the response and newReq is the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only headers listed in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` can be accessed by the Angular client, as part of CORS restrictions.  Simply add your new `test` header to the list. If you use a CORS library it should have a method to whitelist headers.

See examples from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now `test` appears in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` but I still don't see it in `event` nor using `event.headers.get('test')`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` but then gave the wrong example (Access-Control-Allow-Headers) which is for the other direction.   Add "test" to `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` and that should now work.